# Is there a clojure reader literal for keywords?

Tags: clojure

If I have a string ":my.keyword/new" is there a reader literal to use to read it into a keyword? I know there is the keyword function but doing this:

```
(keyword ":my.keyword/new")
```

gives

```
::my.keyword/new
```

and I don't want the double colon

I would rather not have to remove the colon with string/split first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is indeed a [reader literal](http://clojure.org/reference/reader) for keywords:

```
:my.keyword/new
```

If you want to create a keyword programmatically, you can do so with the [`keyword`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keyword) function, as you noted:

```
(keyword "my.keyword/new")
;=> :my.keyword/new
(keyword "my.keyword" "new")
;=> :my.keyword/new
```

Finally, if you want to read a readable form (such as a keyword) into a data structure, you can use [`clojure.edn/read-string`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.edn/read-string):

```
(require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
;=> nil
(edn/read-string ":my.keyword/new")
;=> :my.keyword/new
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `clojure.edn/read-string`:

```
user> (clojure.edn/read-string ":my.keyword/new")
:my.keyword/new
```

This will [safely](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/YBkUaIaRaow) convert string into datastructure.